# Random sum adds to 1000

Tags: mathematics, probability

A random whole number is generated between 1 and 1000 inclusive, and added to a sum. A new randomly generated whole number is generated and added to the sum until the total sum is greater than or equal to 1000.

What is the probability such that the sum adds up to exactly 1000 before exceeding it?

Comment: Seems like a straightforward maths question, not a puzzle in any way.

Comment: @Earlien To me, solving this feels a lot like solving a puzzle, and very little like solving a math problem, so I'm not going to VTC. Other people may have other opinions, of course.

Comment: @Bass It's not exactly a generally useful theorem, so what is it if not a puzzle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we start at $0$ the prob is

> $\frac 1 {1000} \left [ 1 + \frac 1 {1000}\right ]^{999} \approx \frac e {1001}$

This can be shown by

> induction ot a direct combinatorial argument. Let's sketch the second one. Starting at zero there is one way of getting there in one step there are $999$ ways of getting there in two steps because there are $999$ stepping stones. Next, there are $\begin{pmatrix} 999\\2 \end{pmatrix}$ ways of getting there in three steps etc. probability for each step is $\frac 1 {1000}$. So we get the expression by comparing to the binomial formula.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll attempt to get closer to answer by using sticks and stones. The answer should be a fraction between 0 and 1. The numerator should be the number of permutations of the following fashion: $n \in [1,1000]$ stones and $1000 - n$ sticks. The stones represent skips and the sticks represent sums. So for example a permutation like OOOIOOOIOIIOI... would be $4 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 2 + \dots$. The denominator should be something like $n \in [1,1000]$ stones, $m \in [1,999]$ sticks, and $p \in [1,999]$ stones. This represents all the cases including overshooting 1000 by up to 999.

My numbers might be off by 1 or 2 here and there so I invite others to refine this answer if you think it's on the right track.

Comment: You have broadly the right ideas, though the devil is in the detail here. May I shamelessly promote and point you to my own answer which sketches the correct way of doing the combinatorial argument?

Answer (score 0):

Another argument could be

> The recursion argument. Consider quite opposite (but equivalent) process: we have $1000$ and subtract the same random numbers from the current number until we get $0$ or less. Let's say we have $n$, and denote $f(n)$ the probability of reaching exactly $0$ from $n$. We have $$f(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1000}\cdot f(n-i),\quad f(0)=1$$ thus we can compute $f(1)$, then $f(2),\,\ldots$ and eventually $f(1000)=\frac{1001^{999}}{1000^{1000}}\approx \frac{e}{1001.5}$.

This approach python source code is [here](https://tio.run/##VY7BasMwEETP1lfsJURS20Qmlzrgaz8g15CDqFeNQrUSK7m4lH67K5vQ0sswvNlZJn2Wa6TDc@J5dhwDOLavxUfK4EOKXODlDsBmOIk7DLZcxdB/meNJtupbDOjASVJH0XgHBJ5gqL5hLCNXf6aLaBbt6/1ja4xROo9BOnlT4CLDbakwfiBnHOSZnvyK/YotvWGt0UOrLkqJf1@n3sn1n0jsqcgt7jduu5HLwh1Oqc7bu/doi5xU7dqcse6fdjQGZFsi932tt1p3XfeXDkgxePrNjdaLzvMP), although it needs like $85$ seconds out of given $60$ to complete.

Comment: You can dispense with the sum by looking at $f(n)-f(n-1)$ which are the same except $f(n)$ has one more term in the sum representation. That should speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: In fact, it gives $f(n) = \frac{1001}{1000} f(n-1)$ at which point I'd say the computer is no longer required ;-)